# Using || (or) or other operator?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, authentication

I'm creating a login system and wanted to add three more hardcoded login details to my code. I currently have one that requires a username, password and student number to login. When prompted to enter code in the console, the entries must match the hardcoded details to gain authentication. I would like to add three more login details, so there will be four in total. Here is my login system as it currently stands;

```
    final String UserID = "TomDeponeo"; 
    final String Password = "LJMU";
    final int StudentNumber = 22334455;


    String EnteredUserID; 
    String EnteredPassword;
    int EnteredStudentNumber;
    for (int s = 0; s <= 3; s++) { 
        if (s < 3) { 
            System.out.println("Enter your UserID to access lift;"); 
            EnteredUserID = console.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Your UserID is >>> " + EnteredUserID);
            System.out.println("Enter your password to authenticate login;");
            EnteredPassword = console.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Password Entered is >>> " + EnteredPassword);
            System.out.println("Enter your student number to finalise login and authentication;");
            EnteredStudentNumber = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Student Number Entered is >>> " + EnteredStudentNumber);
            if (UserID.equals(EnteredUserID) && (Password.equals(EnteredPassword)) 
                    && (StudentNumber == EnteredStudentNumber)) {
                System.out.println("Athentication complete!");
                System.out.println("***Elevator access granted!***");
                System.out.println("Welcome..."); 
                Elevator a = new Elevator(); 
                Elevator.selectFloor();
                break;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong UserID, Password or Student Number. Please try again."); 
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("3 incorrect enteries detected. Access Denied!"); 
        }
    }
}
```

I currently only have one set of login details, but would like to add more. Here is an example of what I mean;

```
final String UserID = "TomDeponeo"; 
final String Password = "LJMU";
final int StudentNumber = 22334455;

final String UserID2 ="Secondname";
final String Password2 = "Secondpassword";
final String StudentNumber2 = "123456";

//etc...

String EnteredUserID2; 
String EnteredPassword2;
int EnteredStudentNumber2;

//etc...
```

The main part of this question relates to adding in the other possible login details to the login system. Would I need to use `||` to allow for other possible entries? Other details will be added here;

```
if (UserID.equals(EnteredUserID) && (Password.equals(EnteredPassword)) 
                    && (StudentNumber == EnteredStudentNumber)) {
```

To something like this possibly?

```
if (UserID.equals(EnteredUserID) && (Password.equals(EnteredPassword)) 
      && (StudentNumber == EnteredStudentNumber)) {
      || (UserID2.equals(EnteredUserID2) && (Password2.equals(EnteredPassword2)) 
      && (StudentNumber2 == EnteredStudentNumber2))
```

Only 1 set of the possible 4 logins is needed to login.

Comment: Try to read about naming conventions in Java. It's hard to read your code.

Comment: The last example you posted will work except that you forgot to move the `{`.  However, making one big `if` statement with lots of similar tests isn't the right way to program.  You definitely want to create some kind of data structure to hold a list of allowable names/passwords/student numbers.  cheseaux's answer is a good start.

Comment: Also, maybe this is obvious, but in real life you can't hard-code passwords into a program, since someone could find the password just by looking at the binaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good example of why Object programming is necessary in that case.

You should create a class which contains three fields, namely

```
class User {

    String userID; 
    String password;
    int studentNumber;

    public User(String userID, String pass, int number) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.password = pass;
        this.studentNumber = number;
    }
}
```

So that you can have an `ArrayList<User>` of `User` instances. You can then easily iterate over this list to find any matching credentials.

Comment: Or even better, a `Map` keyed on the user ID.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a nice object:

```
public class Credentials {

    private final String name;
    private final String password;
    private final String studentNumber;

    public Credentials(String name, String password, String studentNumber) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Credentials other = (Credentials) obj;
        if (!this.name.equals(other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!this.password.equals(other.password)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!this.studentNumber.equals(other.studentNumber)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

And in your test class:

```
private static final Credentials[] cred = {
    new Credentials("TomDeponeo", "LJMU", "22334455"),
    new Credentials("Secondname", "Secondpassword", "123456"),
    /* ... */
};
```

Then to test for entered credentials:

```
public static boolean checkForCredentials(String EnteredUserID, String EnteredPassword, String EnteredStudentNumber) {
    Credentials entered = new Credentials(EnteredUserID, EnteredPassword, EnteredStudentNumber);

    for (Credentials creds : validCredentials) {
        if (creds.equals(entered)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

With this you can have an undefined number of hardcoded credentials without touching the logic. Be aware that I have overrided `equals` but not `hashCode`. This is for example, in real world, you always want to override both `hashCode` AND `equals` or none.

Comment: Does anyone else use `super()` on classes that aren't extended from anything?  I don't.  :)

Comment: Each class is extended from `Object`

Comment: I meant explicitly extended.

Answer (score -1):

You were close. This is the correct boolean logic you are looking for:

```
if ((UserID.equals(EnteredUserID) && Password.equals(EnteredPassword) && StudentNumber == EnteredStudentNumber) 
|| (UserID2.equals(EnteredUserID2) && Password2.equals(EnteredPassword2) && StudentNumber2.Equals(EnteredStudentNumber2)))
```

Notice, the EnteredStudentNumber2 variable is a string, so you will have to use .Equals().

The first EnteredStudentNumber is an integer, so you can use == comparison.

Comment: No. He was using == operator when comparing the EnteredStudentNumber variable(String to String comparison), as I pointed out in my post.

Comment: yes, sorry, I didn't spot that the second number was declared as a `String` (but it was probably a typo?).

Answer (score -1):

As others have stated it is possible to do this with the or operator (`||`)

You would want to group your checks for all the fields with parantheses around them then or for the other checks

```
    if ((UserID.equals(EnteredUserID) && (Password.equals(EnteredPassword)) && (StudentNumber == EnteredStudentNumber))
            || (UserID2.equals(EnteredUserID) && (Password2.equals(EnteredPassword)) && (StudentNumber2 == EnteredStudentNumber))
            [...]
            )
```

However this probably isn't such a great idea as it's very error prone (you could accidentally check StudentNumber4 in a block that is supposed to check StudentNumber43, therefore you should be working with some kind of Iterable Data structure. That can multiple `List<String>`, multiple String Arrays `String[]` or lists of objects encapsulating your UserInformation (`List<User>` or `User[]`)